# Debugging tools/methodology for tclsh8.5

Tags: debugging, api, tcl

I've been attempting to debug some issues I'm having with calling a vendor specific TCL API.  Needless to say, the API crashes at a certain point and the stderr output leaves something to be desired.  Also, nothing of note in the standard /var/log/* areas either.  Is there a good debugger for TCL that can perhaps give me more information on the issue?  This is running on FC14, and I'm aware of the trace command provided by TCL, wanted to know if there were more options out there...

Comment: Does it crash in Tcl (that is, script) code or C code loaded into Tcl? It's not quite clear (to me) from the problem description.

Comment: Actually, most of the vendor binaries and libraries are compiled ActiveTCL .tcl files.  I see the API call that the program is failing at, it appears to be calling an external Java class that it uses.  Once I find out more, I will post.

Comment: ah, so you mean its bytecode-precompiled Tcl? (I'm talking about http://wiki.tcl.tk/tbcload)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of suggestions here http://wiki.tcl.tk/473. Unfortunately I can't really recommend anything as I've never found a need for a TCL debugger, but then again I havent' been in your position with a vendor API. Feel free to ask for further help!